# Is there a possibility to read ".xlw" files in R / Python

Tags: python, r, excel

I have several very, very old files of interest I'd like to work in R with. They are Excel 4 files, ".xlw" (back from the 90s).

I cant convert them all manually to .xls or .xlsx files, they are way too much. I also did not find any freeware to do so.

Does anybody knows an R library (or Python or whatever) or a freeware software to convert these files?

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xlrd` python module is capable of reading .`xlw` files:

```
import xlrd
book_data = xlrd.open_workbook("your_example.xlw")
```

You can also specify `xlrd` as engine in pandas to read the data as dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
xl_data = pd.read_excel("your_example.xlw", engine = "xlrd")
```